# Geoserver / Geowebcache diskquota.index.db H2 quota database file is 120GB, how to reorg / shrink or delete/rebuild?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I have Geoserver 2.8.2 running on a Windows server in Tomcat.  I have a drive specifically setup just for GeoWebCache.  All has been fine until today, I restarted the machine, and discover that drive is out of disk space.  It is 126GB in size, and was using about 6GB.  I discovered that the "diskquota.index.db" file is 120GB in size.  The diskquota.data.db is only 37MB. Clearly something has gone wrong.

I think I need to somehow reset / delete / recreate this database, but I'm not entirely sure what the proper procedures would be to do so.

Here is the directory listing for that folder:

```
05/22/2017  12:03 PM    <DIR>          .
05/22/2017  12:03 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/22/2017  12:03 PM        38,584,368 diskquota.data.db
05/22/2017  12:03 PM   123,511,767,088 diskquota.index.db
05/22/2017  12:03 PM           705,672 diskquota.trace.db
           3 File(s) 123,551,057,128 bytes
           2 Dir(s)         565,248 bytes free
```

Comment: If you really want to delete, while in that folder, `sudo rm -rf file.db` and open Geoserver, under tile layers clear the cache on the layer. You should also set disk quota for your caching so you cache does not get out of hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem like this:  I turned off the tile quota (unchecked it to disable it).  I restarted the Geoserver.  I then deleted the database files from the folder, all of them.  Then I turned the quota back on, and it recreated the database. It seemed when it completed though that the "used" amount was less than the disk space actually in use.  Today, the number looks more accurate.  I don't know exactly how it works.  But since I've used only about 5-6GB and the quota is 100GB, I think it will be fine.  I certainly don't want to get rid of the currently cached tiles...

Comment: Mind, 2.8.x is old and still has a bug in the quota database management which has been solved in 2.10.x/2.11.x (don't be fooled by the 2.9.5 tag, it has never been released): https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-5615